# Errors when trying to install node fibers

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, fibers

I'm trying to install node fibers for use with my Meteor app on a Windows server that does not have an internet connection. I've manually copied the fibers files from github to the `programs/server/node_modules/fibers` directory as per the package readme. I'm now trying to run `npm install --verbose` from that directory. I'm receiving the following error:

```
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: v0.10.40
gyp verb command install [ 'v0.10.40' ]
gyp verb install input version string "v0.10.40"
gyp verb install installing version: 0.10.40
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 0.10.40
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created C:\Users\xilapko\.node-gyp\0.10.40
gyp verb created nodedir C:\Users\xilapko\.node-gyp\0.10.40
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.40/node-v0.10.40.tar.gz
gyp http 503 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.40/node-v0.10.40.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp verb command remove [ '0.10.40' ]
gyp verb remove using node-gyp dir: C:\Users\xilapko\.node-gyp
gyp verb remove removing target version: 0.10.40
gyp verb remove removing development files for version: 0.10.40
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: 503 status code downloading tarball
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nod
e-gyp\lib\install.js:246:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onResponse (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\requ
est\request.js:1085:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (http.js:1689:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:122:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1584:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\
node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
```

Note that I already have node v0.10.40 installed on the server (`node -v` confirms this) so I don't understand why it's trying to download this version again from the internet.